# PHP Local max_execution_time not changing

Tags: php, nginx

I am running nginx php5-fpm and I noticed,that I cannot change the local php setting for max execution time. The master set in the fpm php.ini file is set to 300 but when I check the php settings it has a local value of 0 and master 300. I have tried to put a php.ini file inside the root of the folder with a local setting for max execution time but no change is being made.

Comment: After every change you have to restart the apache server.

Comment: yes i did change it and restart

Comment: why would you downvote my question if you dont even have a solution.

Comment: Where did you check the max execution time for local? In cli default it's 0 (so no max). And in browser default is 30, so probably it's changed to 300 now.

Comment: Its not for that you have not followed the nginx tutorial properly. You have to change the www.conf file and set request_terminate_timeout = 300. Also if you are using virtual host you have to add this line at the bottom of each host fastcgi_read_timeout 300; When you ask any question you have to jot down each step you have followed.

Comment: Yes my nginx is set up properly already with the parameters. Thank you to daniel as it seems his response is correct. CLI is hardcoded to 0.